# How can I cout all combination of shots from Basketball games

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

I am trying to solve a problem with memset, but I am trying to get the combination of shots that can give me 5.

I don't know if I am using the memset function correctly to solve a dynamic programming problem, although I have a slight perception that I am. My intention with this code is to get all the combinations that given n, I can receive as a response the combinations of the shots that add up to n.

Like that: for N = 5, (5, 0, 0), (2, 0, 1), (1, 2, 0) (0, 1, 1).

Here is the problem:
Basketball games are a sequence of 2-point shots, 3-point shots, and 1- point free throws. Give an algorithm that computes how many possible mixes (1s,2s,3s) of scoring add up to a given n. For n = 5 there are four possible solutions: (5, 0, 0), (2, 0, 1), (1, 2, 0), and (0, 1, 1).

My actual code

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n;  //input value of n 
    cin>>n;
    
    //pushing 1, 2, 3 in a array
    int arr[3] = {1, 2, 3};
    int dp[n+1];
    memset(dp, 0, sizeof(dp));
    dp[0] = 1;//base case
    
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
            if(i>=arr[j]){
        dp[i] += dp[i-arr[j]];  
                                
            }


        }
         cout<<dp[i];
                
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @RetiredNinja hi! thanks for your corrections, already edited my question. My intention is obtain all combination according the input (n).

Comment: What is your question? I think your use of memset is correct; however, you wouldn't need to use it.

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't the most efficient method, though one way to solve this problem would be to generate every possible outcome to a point and then test if this outcome will fit the criteria.

The only thing in my solution that might not work for you as mine does not use memset. I didn't use memset for two reasons, one, I have no experience with it and would have no idea how to use it. Two, after some research into what it does, I agree with Captain Hatteras (he commented on your original post) in how you really do not need it for what you are trying to do. Unless this is a school project and you need to use memset or something, I would just get rid of it.

```
int n;
int totalCombinations = 0;
std::cin >> n; //defines variables for the total combination and takes input for n

//The variables in the for loops represent the amount of 1 points, 2 points and
//3 points are scored. So if i = 1, there was 1 one point scored. 
//If k = 2, there were 2 3 pointers scored and you get the point.

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < n - i; j++)
    {
        for(int k = 0; k < n - i - j; k++) //These 3 are generating every possible input for the three numbers. 
        //I take the previous numbers away from the generated one to eliminate some combinations that definitely won't work.
        {
            if((i * 1) + (j * 2) + (k * 3) == n) //Here we test if these numbers actually will equal n. 
            {
                std::cout << i << ", " << j << ", " << k << "\n"; //If it does equal n, we cout the combination (I did this for logging purposes, it is optional)
                totalCombinations++; //Then the total combinations is increased
            }
        }
    }
}
std::cout << "Total: " << totalCombinations; //We can then cout total combinations and we get the number
```